# Alternative to eval for accessing object by string name?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following

```
eval(id+' = new MyObject()');
```

and I want to access the resulting object and its methods. I could do so with

```
myObject = eval(id);
myObject.myMethod();
```

but what elegant alternatives are there to using eval?

Comment: Why do you need `eval` at all?

Comment: @Renesis it's possible he doesn't know the actual name of the variable - say the name was generated at runtime or something. but he does know that `id` contains that name and it can be used to programatically get a reference to the real item.

Comment: @lincolnk - I think my question stands, since that's not a common use case in well-organized JS development.

Comment: @Renesis I'm using a third-party library and have to deal with what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `id` is intended to be a global object and you're executing in a browser,

```
window[id] = new MyObject();
myObject = window[id];
myObject.myMethod();
```

Or you could just modify the code to store that `id` into an Object.

```
var objectStore = {};

objectStore[id] = new MyObject();
myObject = objectStore[id];
myObject.myMethod();
```